# Thumbnails broken in CP after migrating images to AWS S3

Tags: image, s3, aws

I migrated my images over to AWS S3 using the Amazon S3 plugin; however, now I'm seeing that the thumbnails in the CP are broken, and a `brokenimage` is displayed.

[image]

The full size images display fine in the CP and the front end. If I re-upload them, the thumbnails display correctly in the CP, but that's not an ideal solution.

Is there a way to make the images display correctly in the CP without re-uploading them?

Comment: Have you tried using the update asset indexes utility in the Control Panel?

Comment: I did not try that. Already re-uploaded everything. Agh!

Comment: I'm new to Craft. Think I read about that at some point. Would that likely have solved it? Feel free to post it as the answer.

Comment: Not sure if it would have solved it, but it's an easy first thing to try! Added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would have been that the asset indexes stored in the database are out of sync since it was recently migrated to a new Volume.

A way to fix that would be to run the "Update Asset Indexes" utility from the Control Panel.

Answer (score 1):

It actually turns out to be an oversight on my part. It was confusing (after I manually replaced the missing assets), but in control `panel > admin > settings > assets > volumes`, I did not have the correct bucket selected for a couple of my volumes. I simply overlooked that option.